# How to fix the error Error connecting to the KeX server?

Tags: linux, vnc

When I run the kex, it gives this error

```
Error connecting to the KeX server.
Please try "kex start" to start the service.
If the server fails to start, please try "kex kill" or restart your WSL2 session and try again.
```

Answer (score 13):

Following Instructions worked for me, remount `/tmp/.X11-unix` with `rw` option:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /tmp/.X11-unix
```

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9303#issuecomment-1345615675

Answer (score 1):

i solved the same problem

```
sudo apt remove -y kali-win-kex && sudo apt install -y kali-win-kex
```

Answer (score 0):

I also was unable to bring up KEX, and found out it was do to an oversight with the WSL version

It turns out I had the KALI BOX still on WSL v1, fixing to WSL v2 fixed it for me

upgrade it first to version 2 using the following command:

```
wsl --set-version kali-linux 2
```

When upgrading the distro to WSL2, you may be prompted to download and install the latest Linux Kernel, which you should do.

You can then enter the `wsl -l -v` command again to confirm that Kali Linux is now configured as a WSL2 distribution.

Now launch Kali Linux and run the following commands to prep the distribution with the latest updates and required files.

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Source: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/kali-linux-gets-a-gui-desktop-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux/

Answer (score 0):

These steps solved it for me:

1. `sudo su` (some commands require root)
2. `cd /tmp`
3. `ls -a`
4. Delete all .XX-lock files you can find (just do `rm .X1-lock`, `rm .X2-lock` ...)
5. `rm -r /tmp/.X11-unix`
6. run `vncserver`
7. run `kex`

Enjoy

Answer (score -1):

After switching to the Windows App version of WSL with 
wsl.exe --update 
I also had this issue.

This fixed the issue:

sudo apt remove -y kali-win-kex && sudo apt install -y kali-win-kex 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo su 
umount /tmp/X11-unix 
rm -r /tmp/.X11-unix
rm /tmp/.X1-lock 
exit 
sudo rm /home/YOURUSERNAME/.Xauthority
vncserver 
kex

Not all steps are necessary..

Somehow
 
kex --win -s 
 fixed the audio so I have audio now. So input that if you have problems with the audio and WSL. Windows is asking you for permission for audiopulse. Confirm and then you would have the audio..
 
 Good luck and a good new year.

Comment: So  if you have also no audio with Kali Linux and WSL on Windows  just open cmd.exe and write: wsl.exe --update  and then in Kali Linux write in your terminal: kex --win -s. Fixed two issues then..